# Derivative inequality for a twice continuously differentiable function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

This is a question from a past exam. I thought that this was easy, but found no way of solving it.

> Let $f: \mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be continuously twice differentiable with $f''(x)\gt0\forall x\in\mathbb R$. Then
>   (a) if $a\lt b$, then $f'(a)\lt\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\lt f'(b)$.
>   (b) if $a\lt x\lt b$, then $f(x)\lt f(a)+\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}(x-a)$.

For $(a)$, I thought that the mean-value theorem suffices, but later I found that, if $f(b)-f(a)=f'(a)$, then the inequality should not hold. How can I prohibit from this to happen?
For $(b)$, I also tried using mean-value theorem, but to no avail. Also, I tried rewriting it as $\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\lt\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. However, I got nothing from this expression either, though I think it has something to do with the solution.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $f$ is convex then $\displaystyle g:x \mapsto \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ is monotically non-decrasing on $[a,+ \infty)$.

> Let $a<x<y$. There exists $\lambda \in (0,1)$ such that $x= (1-\lambda)a+\lambda y$, hence $\displaystyle g(x)= \frac{1}{\lambda} \frac{f((1-\lambda)a+\lambda y)-f(a)}{y-a} \leq \frac{(1-\lambda)f(a)+\lambda f(y) -f(a)}{y-a} = g(y)$.

Comment: And one proves this by use of $(a)$? While $(a)$ can indeed be proved by mean-value theorem? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In fact, it is a simple consequence of the definition of convexity.

Comment: I see. Thanks for dawning on me. But how about $(a)$? I later found that mean-value theorem is insufficient to solve $(a)$. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh! I see. Since this $g$ is monotonically non-decreasing if and only if the inequality in $(a)$ holds, one can first show that $g$ is so, and then both $(a)$ and $(b)$ follow immediately! Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The case that $f(b)=f(a)+f'(a)(b-a)$ happen only when $f''(x)\equiv 0$ for any 
$x\in[a,b]$, because $f(b)=f(a)+f'(a)(b-a)+f''(x)\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}$ with some $x\in [a,b]$ and $f''(x)>0$. From this we can obtain the desired result easily.